# How to use scp to transfer files between ubuntu and windows10?

Tags: ssh, windows, openssh, scp, sshd

I'm using the command `scp -P${myport} ${username}@${ip}` to tranfer the files, but I don't know how to write the filepath in windows.
For example, if the filepath in windows is`C:/Download`, how to write the scp command?

Comment: "to write the filepath in windows." That would be a windows problem and not Ubuntu. I tend to use putty for things like this.

Comment: Instead of scp from Ubuntu to Win10, you might consider using Win10 to take files from Ubuntu; then, you can use programs like Filezilla.

Comment: @Rinzwind Actually, Putty is for terminal access and this post is about file transfers, so not really related.

Comment: @ray no not true. putty is commandline too in windows. executable is called `pscp` (putty scp) Here is the manual https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter5.html But again this is a WINDOWS problem

Comment: @Rinzwind Please elaborate what you mean...  PuTTy under Windows is used to connect to a remote server so that you have command-line access to a remote server.  You can use PuTTy to connect to a remote server and then use scp on that server, but it's scp that's doing the file transfer, not PuTTy.  How do you use PuTTy to transfer files?

Comment: see the link. putty is also command line `pscp c:\documents\foo.txt fred@example.com:/tmp/foo`

Comment: @Rinzwind I see what you mean, even though I don't agree with you.  You're using the term "Putty" to encompass a family of tools.  But Putty is itself a program.  `pscp` is Putty's version of `scp`.  One could also say that Putty is used for public key generation, but I think another sentence saying that the program involved is `puttygen` would be useful.  Yes, I know this is about Windows, but you're the one who brought it up and being clear[er] with even short comments will help new people visiting askubuntu for the first time, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we talking about the new feature of the latest Windows build: [OpenSSH in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview), you just need to quote the Windows path, because it usually contains colon sign `:`, that in general is used to indicate the remote host within `scp`, `rsync`, etc.

So to copy a file from (local)Ubuntu to (remote)Window you can use a command as:

```bsh
scp ./test.txt user@windows-host:'D:\Downloads\'
```

To copy a file from (remote)Window to (local)Ubuntu you need to add the option `-T` ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599326/6543935)) then the command will look as:

```bsh
scp -T user@windows-host:'D:\Downloads\test.txt' ./
```

```bsh
scp -T user@windows-host:'D:\Downloads\*.*' ./
```

Comment: `scp user@191.x.x.x:D:/\Projects/\test/\test.rar .` worked for me